# How do I fill 2D array with increasing numbers from one point

Tags: c#, arrays, recursion

What I want to achieve is this:

8 7 6 5 6 7 8
7 6 5 4 5 6 7
6 5 4 3 4 5 6
5 4 3 2 3 4 5
4 3 2 **1** 2 3 4
5 4 3 2 3 4 5
6 5 4 3 4 5 6
7 6 5 4 5 6 7
8 7 6 5 6 7 8

1 - starting point from given coordinates (X;Y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like:

```
for(var i = 0;i<array.GetLength(0);i++)
{
    for(var j = 0;j<array.GetLength(1);j++)
    {
        array[i,j] = 1 + Math.Abs(targetI - i) + Math.Abs(targetJ - j);
    }
}
```

I don't believe that's perfect, but it should be enough to point you in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

No recursion needed :)

Basically, you want the array to be filled with the [Manhattan distance + 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) between the cell's coordinate and the target coordinate -- i.e. `abs(x - tx) + abs(y - ty) + 1`.

Here's a solution in JavaScript that just prints out such an array; it's left as an exercise to the reader (I've always wanted to say that!) to translate it to C# and make it assign to an array of your liking.

```
function fillArray(w, h, targetX, targetY) {
    for(var y = 0; y < h; y++) {
        var t = [];
        for(var x = 0; x < w; x++) {
            t.push(Math.abs(x - targetX) + Math.abs(y - targetY) + 1);
        }
        console.log(t);
    }
}

fillArray(7, 9, 3, 4);
```

Sample output:

```
[ 8, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
[ 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
[ 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
[ 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
[ 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]
[ 6, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6 ]
[ 7, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7 ]
[ 8, 7, 6, 5, 6, 7, 8 ]
```

Answer (score 1):

use Rec(x,y,0) in your code, where mas its your array, and maxx and maxy its size of array

```
static public void Rec(int x, int y, int counter)
    {
        if (mas[x, y] == 0)
        {
            counter++;
            mas[x, y] = counter;
            if (x - 1 >= 0)
            {
                Rec(x - 1, y, counter);
                if (y - 1 >= 0)
                    Rec(x - 1, y - 1, counter);
            }
            if (y - 1 >= 0)
            {
                Rec(x, y - 1, counter);
                if (x + 1 <= maxx)
                {
                    Rec(x + 1, y - 1, counter);
                }
            }
            if (x + 1 <= maxx)
            {
                Rec(x + 1, y, counter);
                if (y + 1 <= maxy)
                {
                    Rec(x + 1, y + 1, counter);
                }
            }
            if (y + 1 <= maxy)
            {
                Rec(x, y + 1, counter);
                if (x - 1 >= 0)
                {
                    Rec(x - 1, y + 1, counter);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```